# How do I add a dash indent line to VS code like this?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

This lines from left side which help to structure the code for writing and reading also.

[image]

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAmOt5_fMtU

Comment: Thanks man! you make my life easy! it's really works for me.

Answer (score 2):

- GoTo VS code setting==> search: `PreviewUI` ==> check `Dart:Preview flutter Ui Guides`

[image]