# Flutter: How to make the code visualization in VS Code look like this

Tags: flutter

I need to set up a widget delimiter in this style.

I can't find how to do it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, can you try to rephrase your question ?

Comment: Updated the picture, I was wondering how to enable the display of such lines.

Comment: If you're trying to add a dash indent line to your VS Code editor, This might help you: ***https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770945/how-do-i-add-a-dash-indent-line-to-vs-code-like-this.*** Take a look and see if it answers your question. ***Hope this help you!***